# How do i add a style to notifications in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

```
this.$notify({
        title: 'İşlem Başarılı',
        message: 'REQUEST SUCCESSFULLY SAVED',
        type: 'success',
        classes: 'notfClas'
      })
```

When i add a class it doesn't see it. How do i add a style to notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [vue-notifications package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-notification) you can manage it's settings (including the list of classes) via the component props as [described here](https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification/blob/master/README.md#component-props). Like:

```
<notifications classes="your-class-name"/>
```

There is also a small example that may be usefull http://vue-notification.yev.io/

Comment: I am using Element UI .It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

change `classes` to `customClass`

> Attribute: customClass

> Description: custom class name for Notification

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/notification